# Find intersections in all dataset rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I need to write a function.

It takes any value from the dataset as input and should look for an intersection in all rows.

For example:
phone = 87778885566

The table is represented by the following fields:

1. key
2. id
3. phone
4. email

Test data:

- 1; 12345; 89997776655; test@gmail.com
- 2; 54321; 87778885566; two@gmail.com
- 3; 98765; 87776664577; three@gmail.com
- 4; 66678; 87778885566; four@gmail.com
- 5; 34567; 84547895566; four@gmail.com
- 6; 34567; 89087545678; five@gmail.com

The output should be:

- 2; 54321; **87778885566;** two@gmail.com
- 4; 66678; **87778885566;** **four@gmail.com**
- 5; **34567;** 84547895566; **four@gmail.com**
- 6; **34567;** 89087545678; five@gmail.com

It should check all values ​​and if values ​​intersect somewhere, return a dataset with intersections.

Comment: Can you explain how key=[5,6] should up in the output?

Comment: At the output, you should get a dataframe 2.4 (intersection by phone) 4.5 (intersection by email) 5.6 intersection by id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `recurssion`:

```
import numpy as np

def relation(dat, values):
    d = dat.apply(lambda x: x.isin(values.ravel()))
    values1 = dat.iloc[np.unique(np.where(d)[0]),:]
    if set(np.array(values)) == set(values1.to_numpy().ravel()):
        return values1
    else:
        return relation(dat, values1.to_numpy().ravel())

relation(df.astype(str), np.array(['87778885566']))

       1            2               3
1  54321  87778885566   two@gmail.com
3  66678  87778885566  four@gmail.com
4  34567  84547895566  four@gmail.com
5  34567  89087545678  five@gmail.com
```